# PHP o el navegador no me muestra los errores en pantalla

Tags: php

que tal estoy usando ubuntu 20 quiero saber porque cuando tengo un error en php este no me aparece ni me manda nada ya configure el navegador pero igual no me deja mostrar mis errores o es php o no se que sea

aqui muestro lo que se supone que es un error porque cambia la contraseña de mi codigo pero en la pantalla no me muestran los errores nose que sea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya borre cookies y use otros navegadores

aqui muestro el error que me deberia aparecer en el navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me aparece solo que esta pagina no funciona y cuando si esta bien el codigo la pagina si funciona bien y normal osea solo es cuando tengo errores en php pero de ser asi estoy tratando de hacer que eso errores me los muestre en el navegador

aquiero que se vean asi en mi navegador los errores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias ser más especifico?, que es lo que hace tu web? Que tienes en php?. El error es error de tu servidor.

Comment: a ver acabo de editar la pregunta

Comment: El editor te dice el error. Quita el ```;``` de la llave ```}```

Comment: si yo lo agrege ese error a proposito es que as de cuenta que cuando marca un error php este lo muestra en el navegador y en el IDE pero aqui cuando marca un error este no me lo muestra en el navegador y es lo que quiero

Comment: El error que tienes es de sintaxis

Comment: ok y como hago para que eso me lo muestre en el navegador? osea quiero ver el error en el navegador pero en vez de eso me sale 500

Comment: Php te mostrará los errores en el navegador si los errores son ocasionados en tiempo de ejecución por ejemplo una mal conexión a la BD o variable no definida. Como utilizas Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu es tu SO o es un servidor apache?

Comment: si pero en mi navegador no me los muestra y utilizo ubuntu es xampp el que tengo instalado

Comment: Ya entendí, pero aun no se por que no se te muestra de tal forma, lo siento por no poder ayudarte, investigaré y si encuentro algo te aviso.

Comment: gracias muy amable

Comment: Si pones esto **al inicio de tu script** debería mostrarte los errores en pantalla: **`ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`** Haciendo esto no es necesario modificar la configuración en `php.ini`

Comment: gracias grcias si me sirvio

Comment: Dicen que la ropa sucia se lava en casa. Mientras desarrollas puede ser cómodo, pero realmente no quieres que un usuario vea ese tipo de cosas, lo puedes traumar. Después de todo no es tan difícil acostumbrarse a revisar los logs del servidor web, en especial los de php.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una forma

Lo puede haces desde el código de la siguiente forma

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
```

**Desde el archivo php.ini**

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = On
En este caso, indicamos que nos
```

Comment: que tal agrege este codigo en xampp ini y me mando error no me dejaba iniciar asi que lo quite

Comment: Es el php.ini ..